# Swagger integration into Dropwizard

Tags: api, rest, swagger, dropwizard, swagger-ui

I am fairly new to drop wizard (dropwizard.io) & just completed their tutorial. I would like to integrate Swagger (swagger.io) into this sample app.
I found:

- github.com/federecio/dropwizard-swagger-sample-app
- github.com/federecio/dropwizard-swagger

The generated JSON seems to be quite similar, however I cannot expand the REST resources to see their respective operations.
The only difference I noted was that the example code of the swagger integration uses SERVER whereas the official drop wizard example is using APPLICATION

Here an Image (i.stack.imgur.com/QzhPa.png)

Please could you tell me what is wrong in my approach.
Thank you very much. Here is the code to my approach: https://github.com/geoHeil/dropwizardSwaggerIntegrationNotWorking

Edit:

```js
for api - docs {
  "apiVersion": "0.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "apis": [{
    "path": "/sample"
  }, {
    "path": "/hello-world",
    "description": "Operations about greetings"
  }]
}


for sample {
  "apiVersion": "0.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "basePath": "http://geoHeil.local:8080",
  "resourcePath": "/sample",
  "apis": [{
    "path": "/sample",
    "operations": [{
      "method": "GET",
      "summary": "Sample endpoint",
      "notes": "",
      "type": "void",
      "nickname": "get",
      "authorizations": {},
      "parameters": []
    }]
  }, {
    "path": "/sample/hello-with-path-param/{name}",
    "operations": [{
      "method": "GET",
      "summary": "Sample endpoint with path param",
      "notes": "",
      "type": "void",
      "nickname": "getWithPathParam",
      "authorizations": {},
      "parameters": [{
        "name": "name",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "paramType": "path"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "path": "/sample/hello-with-query-param",
    "operations": [{
      "method": "GET",
      "summary": "Sample endpoint with query param",
      "notes": "",
      "type": "void",
      "nickname": "getWithQueryParam",
      "authorizations": {},
      "parameters": [{
        "name": "name",
        "required": false,
        "type": "string",
        "paramType": "query"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}

for hello - world {
  "apiVersion": "0.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "basePath": "http://geoHeil.local:8080",
  "resourcePath": "/hello-world",
  "apis": [{
    "path": "/hello-world",
    "operations": [{
      "method": "GET",
      "summary": "Greetings endpoint",
      "notes": "",
      "type": "void",
      "nickname": "sayHello",
      "authorizations": {},
      "parameters": [{
        "name": "name",
        "required": false,
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "paramType": "query"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Which version of swagger-ui do you use? You can check the top of the swagger-ui.js file.

Comment: I was using:<dependency>
    <groupId>io.federecio</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.2</version>
</dependency> a picture can be found https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsvfpvahp3ari3r/Swagger_UI.png?dl=0 I could NOT find version information on the top of the js file.

Comment: But in the JS console some errors like UncaughtType error showed up

Comment: I don't have a dropwizard environment ready. Any chance you can edit the question and past both the output of your /api-docs and /api-docs/sample?

Comment: sure: api-docs:   {"apiVersion":"0.0","swaggerVersion":"1.2","apis":[{"path":"/sample"},{"path":"/hello-world","description":"Operations about greetings"}]}

Comment: That's only the /api-docs. I need the output of /api-docs/sample and /api-docs/hello-world as well. You won't be able to post it in a comment, you have to edit the question.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztrj1j7ogpgxw0z/Swagger_UI.txt?dl=0 (was too long for a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything obvious in the generated JSON that would cause the operations to not expand.

However, the swagger-ui bundled with the dropwizard-swagger package is a bit old. I would try using the newer version of swagger-ui.

I'm not sure if it would conflict with the bundled swagger-ui or not, but basically you need to clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui and copy the /dist directory to your static content.

Another option is to run the swagger-ui locally (just for testing purposes) but opening the /dist/index.html and pointing it at your /api-docs directory. However, in order for that to work properly, you'd need to enable CORS - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#cors-support.

EDIT:

I didn't notice you edited the question with the JSON, and it made it easier to read.
There's a problem with the GET /hello-world operation. It looks like it's supposed to accept an array of strings as a query parameter, but the parameter is missing a `"type": "array"` in its definition. I can't say what may be causing it without seeing the method's declaration and its annotations, but that's what you should be looking at.

Answer (score 6):

There is now a Swagger spec 2.0 example available:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/master/java/java-dropwizard

This uses the latest swagger core libraries with minimal dependencies.  Note, the version of Jackson needed to be updated from dropwizard's 2.3.2 to swagger's 2.4.2.